# Merging tables with two different dates (SQL)

Tags: sql, date, join, merge, netezza

I'm trying to merge two tables that have different date fields, and am having hard time figuring out best way to show them both...

I have one table that has:

```
id    date_1       daily_count
----------------------------
1     1/1/20           1
1     1/2/20           1 
1     1/3/20           2 
2     1/1/20           3 
2     2/1/20           1
```

and I have another table that has:

```
id    date_2 
-------------
1     1/1/20           
1     1/2/20
1     1/2/20      
1     1/4/20 
1     1/7/20          
2     1/4/20           
2     2/1/20
```

I want to show something like:

```
id    date_1    daily_count    date_2    date_2_count
------------------------------------------------------
1     1/1/20         1         1/1/20          1
1     1/2/20         1         1/2/20          2
1     1/3/20         2          null          null
1      null         null       1/4/20          1 
1      null         null       1/7/20          1 
2     1/1/20         3          null          null 
2      null         null       1/4/20          1 
2     2/1/20         1         2/1/20          1
```

Is it at all possible to do so? Whenever I try to join these two tables using id, I keep getting duplicate values of date_2 per each date_1, and feel super lost.. any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, t1.date, t1.daily_count,
       t2.date, t2.daily_count
from table1 t1 full join
     (select t2.id, t2.date, count(*) as daily_count
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.id, t2.date
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is! The duplicate values are caused by joining on `id` only. From the look of it, you'll need to join on both `id` and `table1.date_1 = table2.date_2` to get one row for each. The other thing—and it's not clear whether you're doing this already without seeing the query—is that you'll need to use `full outer join` to ensure you keep values from both tables, even if one side doesn't have a particular ID/date.